# SFTP Client with source for ipv6

Tags: delphi, sftp, ipv6

I currently use TFTPCLIENT by Xavier Cirac at  http://www.waveflow.com/vcl.htm . 
I have made significant modifications to the source to add some special commands for the mainframe class computer(HP NonStop or Tandem) that is the FTP server.

I now need to add IPv6 and SFTP capability and that does not seem to be a possibility with my current component.

Does anyone know of any Delphi component with source that I can use.

Free or shareware would be nice but I need it enough I will pay for a retail version if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) includes FTP/FTPS and SFTP components with IPv6 support. Components support sending custom commands so you won't need to modify the source code (though it's provided of you need it).

Answer (score 3):

Commercial SFTP - [ELDOS](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-sftp.php), [nSoftware](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssh/components.aspx)

Open Source - [Ararat Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download). It has a SFTP demo, I have used it successfully with Delphi 7 and 2007, but it is not ready for Unicode